# Edge defaults to IE8. No way to force it not to

Tags: internet-explorer-8, microsoft-edge

Edge defaults to IE8 when displaying our app.

1. Tools->Compatitibity View Settings

   - the list is empty
   - the "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" is NOT checked
   - The website is actually treated as "Internet"
2. We have tried both with and without

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
   ```

In short, try as I might Edge defaults to IE8.

Comment: Sounds like you've covered most of the usual bases. One question: Are you viewing it inside a frame belonging to another site? Because that will override any modes on the framed page and use the same mode as the parent frame.

Comment: Nope, going directly to the main URL.